# XamDataGrid Parent Amount should be auto update

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

It seems like that it would be easy but i m having trouble finding the right way to do it.

I am using XamDataGrid and the hierarchy high level look like this.

Account ,Amount --> Sub Account Amount

Here is the screen that help you to understand clearly[image]

**My question is that When i edit the sub accounts amount it should be automatically sums up to it parent amount**

Here is the XAML,

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but I don't have the rep yet.

I can't see how you're binding to your ViewModel, but I would imagine that the ViewModel has the correct values, but you need to tell the View to update.  My ViewModelBase class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and so in my case I would need to call RaisePropertyChanged on the ViewModel property that represents the parent row.

If this doesn't work, please post a simple, stripped-down example.